# ASP.net MVC 3 Scaffolding [Display(Name="Hi there")] Wont work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model, attributes, scaffolding

For some wierd reason I just cant get my view to "scaffold" correctly.. isnt it correct that the [Display(Name="SomeThing")] attribute is used to set which label/table-header text should be displayed for a property?
If yes, then has anyone else hade problem with this?
If no, then what should I change it too?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post your code please?

Comment: What data type is the property you have the attribute on?

Comment: it will work if you `rebuild` the project keyboard Shortcut is `ctrl+shift+B`

Answer (score 1):

Actually; I know why.

DisplayAttribute is in the System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations namespace, and has a different purpose to DisplayNameAttribute in the System.ComponentModel namespace.

"DisplayAttribute" : "Provides a general-purpose attribute that lets you specify localizable strings for types and members of entity partial classes."

Use [DisplayName("SomeThing")] instead, and it will work...

Comment: You can use the `DisplayAttribute` in the `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` namespace to change the display label.

Comment: Well... does this type of scaffolding even work for the list-scaffolding template?.. still wont work..

Comment: seems like no after a few miniutes of googeling

Comment: @Inx You will need to provide a bit more detail in your question if you want this resolved.

Comment: @Inx, the default scaffolding just use harcoded string on table headers. You need to change it once the Index view is generated in order to internationalize them or something .

Answer (score 0):

You have an Variable instead of Property... 
For example:

instead of that

```
[Display("User Name")]
public string UName;
```

you must have

```
[Display("User Name")]
public string UName { get; set; }
```